# Create a single Query By Form for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I want to create a Query By Form for my Access database which has linked tables from SQL Server database. The database has 30 tables and I want to create a single form to query all the data from all the tables. But I am unable to figure out how to get this started.

Comment: All tables in one query or all tables in 30 different queries or?  Also, is it user driven or automatic?

Comment: It should be user driven. The user selects the fields and criteria from the form.

Comment: Where are you so far?

Comment: I could do a query by form with one table by I can't understand how to include the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form design, look at the property sheet and make sure that "Form" is selected in the dropdown.  Now - look at the "Data" tab, and then look for the "Record Source" area.  Click in there and then click the "..." button.  You should be able to choose multiple tables now and define the joins, and use form values as part of the criteria.